# Trying to get AJAX to work with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi I am trying to get AJAX to work with a simple destroy method in ruby on rails 3.1. In my index.html.erb I have a destroy link which looks like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', travel_datum, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete, :remote=> true %>
```

In my controller in the destroy method I included

```
    respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to travel_data_url }
    format.json { head :ok }
    format.js
   end
```

Finally in my app/views I have a destroy.js.erb which looks like this:

```
  $('#<%= dom_id(@travel_datum) %>').hide();
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Did you add the Rails jQuery UJS adapter?  https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

Comment: Its there.. I'll have someone more experienced review my code next week. I'll hopefully post the issue them.